# Can't display validation errors in the specified locale

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to translate a page (and only one). My problem is that the translation of the page works correctly, but validation errors remain in the default locale.

In my page controller :

```
public function globalPage($locale = 'en')
    {
      $page = Page::where('slug', 'global')->firstOrFail();

      $this->data['title'] = $page->title;
      $this->data['content'] = $page->content;
      $this->data['page'] = $page->withFakes();

      App::setLocale($locale);

      return view('pages.global', $this->data);
    }
```

In my route :

```
Route::get('{locale}/global', ['as'=>'page.global', 'uses'=> 'PageController@globalPage']);
Route::post('post-global', ['as'=>'page.post-global', 'uses'=> 'GlobalController@store']);
```

In my store function :

```
  public function store(GlobalcontestRequest $request, $locale = 'en')
  {

    $global = new Globalcontest();
    $global->firstname = $request->input('firstname');
    $global->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
    $global->email = $request->input('email');
    $global->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $global->lang = $request->input('lang');
    $global->q1 = $request->input('q1');
    $global->q2 = $request->input('q2');
    $global->q3 = $request->input('q3');
    $global->q4 = $request->input('q4');
    $global->q5 = $request->input('q5');

    $global->save();

    App::setLocale($locale);

    return redirect()->to(route('page.global'));
  }
```

How to make validations errors in the same language as the locale I defined with App::setLocale()?

Comment: Create a middleware that runs before your FormRequests and sets the correct locale

Answer (score 0):

Default validation error messages in Laravel are found in resources/lang/*/validation.php

You need to add a folder resources/lang/*your-language*/validation.php

Did you do this?

Comment: Hello Mkk, yes I did it !